# Sleep in android

Tags: android

I am an android developer I have a problem..
I want to be get notified when the phone screen goes to sleep 
PLease Help wiith a sample code.

Comment: This probably belongs on Stack Overflow. It'll be moved there soon, there's no need to make a duplicate post.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcast `Intents`.